# How can I concatenate three defines type: string + number + string?

Tags: c, macros

I would like to construnct the following string using defines

```
#define LOG_FLOAT_MARKER "%s%d.%010d"
```

So far I have

```
  #define EXP (10)
  #define LOG_FLOAT "%s%d.%0"
  #define D "d"
```

I am trying to create a string like this

```
#define LOG_FLOAT_MARKER LOG_FLOAT EXP D
```

but not getting the expected output, some hint?

Comment: You can only concatenate *strings*. `(10)` is not a string. Next time you have problem with macros, ask the compiler to stop after preprocessing you so you can see what it has expanded the macros as.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks, then I can make the string using `#define EXP 10` but I won't be able to use that define for a numeric usage, right?

Comment: You are probably looking for the `*` specifier [http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have `(10)` for `EXP`, since you don't want the parentheses to be part of the result.

You must use stringification, and some hoop-jumping:

```
#define EXP 10

#define JOIN(a, b, c)      a #b c
#define JOIN2(a, b, c)     JOIN(a, b, c)
#define LOG_FLOAT_MARKER   JOIN2(LOG_FLOAT, EXP, D)
```

Also, I think using a preprocessor symbol named just `D` is asking for trouble.

Comment: Thanks @unwind, so as last step `#define LOG_FLOAT_MARKER   JOIN2(LOG_FLOAT, EXP, "d")` would be better?

Comment: @ndarkness Sure, or rename the `D` to something else, or just hard-code it.

Comment: Hi @unwind, it seems not to work if I print `LOG_FLOAT_MARKER` i get `%s%d.%0(10)d` instead of `%s%d.%010d`

Comment: @ndarkness Did you fix `EXP` like I said in the first line of the answer? I added a fixed version to the code for clarity's sake.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understand what you're trying to do. You are probably looking for `*` specifier:

```
printf( "%s%d.%0*d", "string", 1, 1, 1 ); // output: string1.1
printf( "%s%d.%0*d", "string", 1, 2, 2 ); // output: string1.02
printf( "%s%d.%0*d", "string", 1, 3, 3 ); // output: string1.003
```

See [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) for a full explanation on `*`.

Comment: Thanks @ZDF but I don't want to use printf for matters of optimization